# In C# with MongoDb, how can I update a POCO which contains a JObject?

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, serialization, data-structures

On the backend, we have the following model:

```
    public record RoofDesign
    {
        public int CountOfPanels { get; init; }
        public RoofDesignImages? Images { get; init; }
        public JObject? EditorData { get; init; }
    }
```

The end users will design the roofs in a front-end application.
In addition to the finished design, we wish to store information the editor can use to continue the design session at a later time, possibly at another computer.  The backend will never care about the contents of this data, so it is enough for us just to save a JSON.

The `RoofDesign` object is contained in an array in a `PlanningProject` object and I am currently saving it with the following method:

```
        public PlanningProject UpdatePlanning(PlanningProjectUpdate projectUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Plannings.FindOneAndUpdate(
                filter: CreateFilterById<PlanningProject>(projectUpdate.Id),

                update: CreateUpdate(projectUpdate),

                options: new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<PlanningProject, PlanningProject>
                {
                    ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After
                },

                cancellationToken: cancellationToken
            );
        }
```

This works fine if `EditorData` is `undefined` or `null`.

However, if I give it a value, I get both an unexpected result and an exception.

For example, if it is populated from the value:

```
      "editorData": {
        "additionalProp1": [
          null
        ],
        "additionalProp2": [
          null
        ],
        "additionalProp3": [
          null
        ]
      }
```

... in the MongoDb record, it is saved like:

```
            "EditorData" : {
                "additionalProp1" : {
                    "_t" : "JArray",
                    "_v" : [ 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue",
                            "_v" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "additionalProp2" : {
                    "_t" : "JArray",
                    "_v" : [ 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue",
                            "_v" : []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "additionalProp3" : {
                    "_t" : "JArray",
                    "_v" : [ 
                        {
                            "_t" : "JValue",
                            "_v" : []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

And then I get an error like:

> ystem.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the Roofs property of class SoPE.Estimation.PlanningProject: An error occurred while deserializing the EditorData property of class SoPE.Estimation.RoofDesign: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the EditorData property of class SoPE.Estimation.RoofDesign: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
> ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not determine JSON object type for type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]. at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.GetValueType(Nullable`1 current, Object value)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue..ctor(Object value)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableInterfaceImplementerSerializer`2.FinalizeResult(Object accumulator) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DiscriminatedWrapperSerializer`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(String elementName, Int64 flag)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerHelper.DeserializeMembers(BsonDeserializationContext context, Action`2 memberHandler) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DiscriminatedWrapperSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DiscriminatedWrapperSerializer`1.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0(String elementName, Int64 flag)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerHelper.DeserializeMembers(BsonDeserializationContext context, Action`2 memberHandler) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DiscriminatedWrapperSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.DeserializeDocumentRepresentation(BsonDeserializationContext context)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.DictionarySerializerBase`3.DeserializeValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ClassSerializerBase`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.EnumerableSerializerBase`2.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.SerializerBase`1.MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializer.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeMemberValue(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonMemberMap memberMap)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.DeserializeClass(BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonClassMapSerializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.ElementDeserializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyValueDeserializer`1.Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
> at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Deserialize[TValue](IBsonSerializer`1 serializer, BsonDeserializationContext context) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.ProcessCommandResult(ConnectionId connectionId, RawBsonDocument rawBsonDocument)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.ExecuteAttempt(RetryableWriteContext context, Int32 attempt, Nullable`1 transactionNumber, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteOperationExecutor.Execute[TResult](IRetryableWriteOperation`1 operation, RetryableWriteContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.RetryableWriteOperationExecutor.Execute[TResult](IRetryableWriteOperation`1 operation, IWriteBinding binding, Boolean retryRequested, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.FindAndModifyOperationBase`1.Execute(IWriteBinding binding, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IWriteBinding binding, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.ExecuteWriteOperation[TResult](IClientSessionHandle session, IWriteOperation`1 operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindOneAndUpdate[TProjection](IClientSessionHandle session, FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.<>c__DisplayClass57_0`1.b__0(IClientSessionHandle session)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindOneAndUpdate[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, UpdateDefinition`1 update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at SoPE.DbContext.UpdatePlanning(PlanningProjectUpdate projectUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\SOPE\sope-api\SolarPanelEstimation.Mongo\DbContext.cs:line 105
> at SoPE.Estimation.MongoSolarPanelEstimationService.UpdatePlanning(PlanningProjectUpdate projectUpdate, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\SOPE\sope-api\SolarPanelEstimation.Mongo\Estimation\MongoSolarPanelEstimationService.cs:line 186
> at SoPE.Controllers.V1_0.PlanningsController.UpdatePlanning(String id, UpdatePlanningProjectRequest model, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\SOPE\sope-api\SolarPanelEstimation.Api\Controllers\V1_0\PlanningsController.cs:line 90
> at lambda_method542(Closure , Object )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Any ideas how I can fix this?